# Resting elbows on sefer while learning from it

Tags: jewish-books

I read this on the halachipedia website, "Rama [282:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.282.7?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) writes that one may not place a Sefer on one’s lap and lean one’s elbows on it. Sh”t Shelmat Chaim 2:566 (quoted in Piskei Teshuvot 154:23) is lenient if it’s in middle of one’s learning." I tried to find the particular Salmas Chaim that is referenced on hebrewbooks.com but I was not able to find it. Does anyone know if it is on hebrewbooks.com or anywhere else online, and if so could you point me to it, or if anyone has access to that particular Salmas Chaim or that Piskei Teshuvot that is quoted, can you copy and paste it here?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: The Baer Heytev sk 7 says in name of the Rabenu Manoach that while learning in Bet Midrash and there is no place we can make a leniency to sit at the same level as sefer tora. Rabenu Meshulam has a leniency to need only a heyker and orchot Chayim disagree with the leniency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Here**](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46247&st=&pgnum=167&hilite=) in Hebrewbooks is the Shut Salmat Chayim YD 132.

> סימן קלב
>
> הנחת ידיים על ספר תורה או ספרים
>
> ביורה דעה סימן רפ"ב סעיף ז. דלא יניח אדם ספר תורה (וש"ס) על ברכיו ושתי
>   אצילי ידיו עליו. משמע דוקה אם הספר מונח על ברכיו, אבל על גבי שולחן לא
>   הוה בגדר בזיון כשמניח ידיו על הספר. ‏
>
> תשובה: יעיין במסכת סופרים (פרק ג סוף הלכה טו) הכלל כל שהוא דרך
>   בזיון.‏
>
> In Yore Dea siman 282 s. 7 They write that one could not take a Sefer Tora or a volume of Gemara on his knees with hes "elbows" (articulations of the upper members) on it. We understand that if the book is placed on a table this doesn't enter this category if one places his hands on the book.
>
> Answer: See in Masechet Sofrim chapter 3, halacha 15. The rule is to prohibit an attitude of contempt.